# pfbc checkbox all options required

Tags: html, checkbox, pfbc

I am using a PFBC checkbox, and I want to make all options to have attribute required, for HTML5 validation.

Following code is sent to PFBC for rendering, but it doesn't add the 'required' attribute:

```
array (
                'name' => 'agreements',
                'label' => '',
                'type' => 'Checkbox',
                'options' => array('over_18'=>'I am over 18 years of',
                            'understand_risks'=>'I understand the risks',
                'properties'=> array (
                        'required' => array('over_18','understand_risks')
                )
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in another forum. A fix is needed in the PFBC/Element/Checkbox.php, removing the 'required' option as below. After this the html5 validation for checkboxes works like a charm!

```
--- a/PFBC/Element/Checkbox.php
+++ b/PFBC/Element/Checkbox.php
@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@ class Element_Checkbox extends OptionElement {
                        $value = $this->getOptionValue($value);

                        echo '<label class="', $labelClass, '">';
-            echo '<input id="', $this->_attributes["id"], '-', $count, '"', $this->getAttributes(array("id", "class", "value", "checked", "required")), ' value="', $this->filter($value), '"';
+            echo '<input id="', $this->_attributes["id"], '-', $count, '"', $this->getAttributes(array("id", "class", "value", "checked")), ' value="', $this->filter($value), '"';
                        if(in_array($value, $this->_attributes["value"]))
                                echo ' checked="checked"';
                        echo '/> ', $text, ' </label> ';
```